# How to locate specific elements in one matrix and compare those with a second matrix?

Tags: r, object, dataframe, matrix, indexing

Let's have a binary Matrix/ Data Frame:

```
library("Matrix")
df_binary <- data.frame(as.matrix(rsparsematrix(1000, 20,nnz = 800,  rand.x = runif)))
df_binary[df_binary > 0] = 1
```

Now, I would like to create an index-object of all elements of equal value 1. 
 How I can do this in R?

I need something like an index of those entries to compare the entries of the binary matrix with entries of a second matrix. Both matrices are of the same size - if this information could be important.

Comment: Maybe something like this? `which(df_binary ==1 ,arr.ind = TRUE)`

Comment: @MikeH.: super! that is what I was looking for - thx! :)

Comment: if you are actually using sparse matrices to hold your data then these actually store the indices of the non-zero elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list out you could do something along the lines of

```
list_ones <- function(df) {
  out <- list()

  for (col in names(df)) {
    out[[col]] <- which(df[[col]] == 1)
  }

  return(out)
}

list_ones(df_binary)
```